# How to properly get the parent class using a child class?

Tags: laravel, join, orm

I have this parent-child model that define as:

```
class Contract extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');    
    }
}
```

and on my parents model, that is, Customer i have this:

```
public function contracts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contract', 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

and on my `ContractController` I am getting my customer together with its parent model sorted by the parent field using below code:

```
$contracts = Contract::where('status', 'Active')->join('customers', 'contracts.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')->orderBy('customers.customer_number', 'asc')->paginate(100);
```

My problem now is my **contract** view, that is, `index.blade.php` gives me a different id but using this: `$contracts = Contract::where('status', 'Active')->paginate(100);` works fine.

EDIT

As for the contracts index view, I have this:

```
@foreach($contracts as $key => $contract)

<tr>
    <td>{{ $contract->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $contract->customer ? $contract->customer->customer_number : '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ $contract->customer ? $contract->customer->full_name : '' }}</td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

My problem, is this contract id shows a different one. For example, if in my database, Contract X with id 1 that belongs to Customer X, my views shows a different contract id.

Comment: Provide your code in view file too. Maybe you are trying to accessing wrong variable

Comment: different query different result? whats the error?

Comment: My view is very simple, just ```<tr><td>{{ $contract->id }}</td><td>{{ $contract->customer ? $contract->customer->customer_number : '' }}</td></tr>``` inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with relation ,the simple way to do relation is using eager loading like this:

```
$contracts = Contract::with(['customers'=> function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('customers_number', 'asc');
}])->where('status', 'Active')->paginate(100);
```

Comment: whenever i am using that, it gives me an SQL Error: ```Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customers.customers_number'```

Comment: That works, but it is not sorted by my customer_number, instead it is sorted according to my ```contracts``` id.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i manage to solve my problem. Instead of using

```
$contracts = Contract::where('status', 'Active')->join('customers', 'contracts.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')->orderBy('customers.customer_number', 'asc')->paginate(100);
```

i used this:

```
$contracts = Contract::select('contracts.*')->where('status', 'Active')->join('customers', 'contracts.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')->orderBy('customers.customer_number', 'asc')->paginate(100);
```

that i found from this [github link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4962)